# Updating Emacs' Org-mode on Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, emacs, make, org-mode

I'm using **Emacs 24.2**, which comes with **Org-mode 7.8.11** (why am i using Emacs 24.2? Because i needed to install a [precompiled version of AUCTeX for Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html); but that's another story!).

I read pretty much all the documentation available around building and installing Org (Worg, etc.) but i'm not familiar with UNIX stuff---i'm currently using Windows XP SP3. I really don't want to ruin my Org setup since i'm using it extensively.

Currently i have:

- Org-mode 8.2.1 .zip file.
- GNU Win32 'make' (and dependencies) installed in a folder in Windows' PATH; it works when i call it from CMD (typing "make", just to be sure).

Will it work if i install Org through 'make' in Windows, following [this directions](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-build-system.html)? Has anyone done it before? HOW it is done?

Will i have to install it "manually" (i.e. without 'make'), like it is mentioned in the link above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are not comfortable with backing up and being able to restore your setup if things go wrong.  Master that first, and then move on to trying to change something.  With that being said, does your Emacs version come with the ability to `M-x list packages` and install org via that route?  If you are not comfortable backup up and restoring your entire Emacs setup, then leave it alone -- if it is not broken, don't try and fix it.  AUCTeX can also be installed via `M-x list-packages`.

Comment: FYI:  I just downloaded `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip` from http://gnu.mirrorcatalogs.com/emacs/windows/  I unzipped it to the Desktop on Windows XP SP3, and out of the box, I was able to use `M-x list-packages` and I installed AUCTeX 11.87.1 and Org 20131007.  The whole process took less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Just tried this on another system and it worked flawlessly. I migrated my settings (zenburn, .emacs, etc.) and it's done! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance -- I added a generic answer based upon `M-x list-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x list-packages` is the easiest way to install / upgrade packages -- the lisp files are byte-compiled in the process, along with the creation of basic initial settings chosen by the package maintainer / author.  The `.emacs` file will usually need `(require 'package)` and `(package-initialize)` so that the initial settings are loaded when Emacs opens.